# PostGIS - table with 3d points with fast ordering by distance

Tags: postgis, distance, 3d, point

I am pretty new to PostGIS and I am trying to solve the following problem.

I need a table with 3D points (x,y,z) that will contain around 1-10million points. I want to be able to efficiently ask the table for 100-1000 points that are closest to some given point - parameter that is going to be different for each query.

Now, I started playling around this with following table:

> CREATE TABLE aa (   id serial NOT NULL,   point point,   s integer )
>   WITH (   OIDS=FALSE );
>
> CREATE INDEX aa_p_s_idx   ON aa   USING gist   (point );

Queries like this:

> select * from aa order by point <->   '0,0' limit 100;

are lightning fast (between 10-100msec).

But the problems started when I wanted to move to 3D. It seems I cannot use the `point` type anymore - I had to use `geometry`. And the `<->` operator works on 2D distance. I ended up with:

> CREATE TABLE db_testpoints (   id serial NOT NULL,   point geometry
>   NOT NULL,   CONSTRAINT db_testpoints_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
>   CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_point CHECK (st_ndims(point) = 3),
>   CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_point CHECK (geometrytype(point) =
>   'POINT'::text OR point IS NULL),   CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_point CHECK
>   (st_srid(point) = 4326) ) WITH (   OIDS=FALSE );
>
> CREATE INDEX db_testpoints_point_id   ON db_testpoints   USING gist
>   (point );

and even queries:

> select * from db_testpoints order by point <->
>   ST_geomfromewkt('POINT(0 0 0)') limit 100;

take around 2000msec!

1. Is there a possibility to have better performance here if I used some other column type, some other index etc?
2. Is there a similar operator to `<->` that works on 3D? I could probably use some distance function, but I heard then the index would not be used then...

Any pointers appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Update**

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for both queries shed some light:

```
"1. Limit  (cost=0.00..1.28 rows=10 width=24)"
"  ->  Index Scan using aa_p_s_idx on aa  (cost=0.00..985278.95 rows=7691709 width=24)"
"        Order By: (point <-> '(0,0)'::point)"

"2. Limit  (cost=46786.64..46786.66 rows=10 width=136)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=46786.64..49389.14 rows=1041000 width=136)"
"        Sort Key: (((point)::box <-> '(0,0),(0,0)'::box))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on db_testpoints  (cost=0.00..24291.00 rows=1041000 width=136)"
```

So it looks like in the second query, the index is not used at all...how can I use it and is it going to work with 3D?

Comment: Insert "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" to the beginning of your "select" query, and update your question.

Comment: Updated. It shows that the index is not used in the 2nd query. Hm...

Comment: I figured so, but I'm not sure why as I can't reproduce it. For me, with PostGIS 2.0 your second query is using the index and takes ~40 ms on 1M rows of PointZ data (fast).

Comment: Do you want to use the 3d distance or just do the same things with points having a z-value? I don't think you can get the index to work on real 3d distances, but it should be possible to get it ordered by 2d-distances even if the points has z-values.

Comment: To clearify, there is an index option handling more than 2 dimensions, but I don't think <-> operator supports it.

Comment: @Mike maybe it's because I use postgis 1.5. I am updating to 2.0 today, I'll see what happens

Comment: @Nicklas I see. I want to use 3D euclidean distance (or anything similar). I mean, plain distance, my points aren't geographic points. So will <-> operator support it or I have to use ST_3DDistance? ST_3DDistance doesn't use index I think...

Comment: I think that you will have to use ST_3DDistance, but to be sure, ask on the postgis list. Paul Ramsey has done the work with <-> on the PostGIS side and written the POstGIS part of the ndim-index, but he might not see it here.

Comment: And you are right about ST_3DDistance. It cannot use any indexes. It is only the operators <-> and <#> that can use the index to order by distance.

Answer (score 3):

<-> is not supported for 3D indexes (though it looks like you have a 2-d index so it should be doing a 2D check).

Anyway use ST_3DDwithin to use an index

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from db_testpoints WHERE ST_3dDwithin(point,ST_geomfromewkt('POINT(0 0 0)'),somevalue_that_will_guarantee_100_records) ) As foo 
ORDER BY ST_3DDistance(point,ST_geomfromewkt('POINT(0 0 0)'));
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought on using ST_3DDwithin(), but the hard part is in knowing the distance value:). You mentioned 3D index. Am I using 2D index? How can I created the 3D index then and what is the difference?